# IntelliJ: display folder structure like NetBeans

Tags: intellij-idea, netbeans

I prefer IntelliJ over NetBeans for Maven Java development, but I'm wondering how to get the displayed project structure that NetBeans has into my IntelliJ project. Please see the image below.

[image: Project structure of IntelliJ vs NetBeans]

**Edit:** some more information about what I want.

IntelliJ displays the actual folder layout: the folder webapp is under root/main/webapp. However, NetBeans recognizes that this is an important folder and pulls it up to project level, so virtually root/webapp. This is just a visual thing: in reality the folders remain the same.

In this example, the folder is only 1 tier lower in IntelliJ than in NetBeans. But sometimes, the webapp folder is in root/./././webapp (example). Having to open 5 folders before finally ariving at the webapp folder is annoying and by pulling it up it is clearer and it saves time.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean in the image? What it is that you have and what do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Go to settings(as shows in image) of Project Structure.

[image]

Then select Flatten Packages and Hide Entry Middle Packages. You will get structure like Netbeans in the IntelliJ

For more details please visit: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/project-tool-window.html